# How to get radiobuttonlist selected value

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list as below:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdoYN" runat="server" Width="150px">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I know VBScript can handle radio button, but I am using `RadioButtonList`. I have searched online but not found any solution regarding my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
<script  runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  selection = rdoYN.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub
</script>
```

Sample code taken from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_radiobuttonlist).

Comment: My vb script is separate file. I try the code on separate file, hit error.

Comment: @HowardHee What error? Which statement is raising the error? What happens if you don't put the code in a separate file?